# database diagram

Tags: database-design, content-management-system, erd

i want to see a diagram (erd) of a database system which has been designed for cms. would you lpease show me a complete on? tanks

Comment: http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/3118/dru6db.jpg

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Are you looking to get a diagram for a specific CMS? Or for tools to generate a diagram? Something else?

Comment: no i want the diagram itself, not a tool

Comment: OK - so does @Imre L's link give you what you need?

Answer (score 3):

How about n2cms
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best place to look for ER diagrams of typical database applications is Database Answers .org.  [Click Here](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm)

I didn't see anything for CMS, but maybe it's there under a different name.